# Which method gives better insert performance in mysql db table: CSV import or insert statement

Tags: mysql, php, csv

I have combine data from two tables which results in 6727224 rows. I want to insert this data into another mysql db table. Which method should be very fast to insert this number of records. Insert query or CSV file import?

If CSV one is fast, then i will have to first loop through results and insert it into the csv file.

If insert one is fast, i will create one dictionary or array and will loop through it to insert data in one open connection.

Which way is best to do it in short time?

Thanks.

Comment: If it's on the same server: Insert/Select

Comment: Yes. I have created php script. So i will upload it on server and run it from cli. I want to know which one will be fastest, csv import to table or insert statement?

Comment: When both source & target table are on the same server the fastest way is neither Insert nor Import, it's a pure SQL Insert/Select

Comment: Okay.. But query has so many sub queries and its very tough to combine it in one. So i made a php script which is fetching all the records and i will then process for insertion. there is around 8GB of data and i have optimised results to 0.02 secs from 16 sec. will that be faster or i should create a single query having many number of sub-queries?

Comment: You get 8GB of data in 0.2 seconds?

Comment: The optimum tends to be *not* to take out the data from the database to PHP, process it and bring it back. Avoiding this data movement saves a lot of time. As already pointed out by @dnoeth, one single `INSERT INTO table(col1, ..., coln) SELECT ...` will be faster, even if the `SELECT` has many subqueries. I'd only take it to PHP if there are some functions there that are very convenient to a specific case and not easily implementable within the database..

Comment: No @dnoeth. Now My issue is resolved. I have increased Key buffer size and maximum allowed packet values. Have made single index and compound indexes. And processed data from two tables and stored 6800000 ~ 6.8 million rows in third table. It has taken around 5 hours to complete.

Comment: What do you mean "loop through"?  SQL does things en masse; no looping.  See `LOAD DATA INFILE`.